# RAM available on the server but cannot run java app

Tags: java, memory

My server has 24GB of RAM. It is running on Windows Server 2008. Right now, I'm looking and about 80% of it is free. However when I try to run a Java app, the maximum value I can give to its heap size is -`Xmx1500m`. If I try `-Xmx1600m` or `-Xmx2G` the app will fail to start. Is this a problem with Java or my app?

Comment: Do you have a 64bit version of Java installed?

Comment: @MadProgrammer OMG! No! I haven't. Unfortunately I'm not the one who installed Java. I'll upgrade immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

32-bit processes have this limit under Windows. The maximum amount of memory a 32-bit process can use is 2G. You can easily solve this problem by upgrading to a 64-bit version of Java.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm not the one who installed Java. I'll upgrade Thank you. immediately. Funny!

Comment: @AlirezaNoori +1 The 32-bit emulation environment for Windows emulates all it's limitations as well.  You will be lucky to get 1.5 GB heap space under 32-bit windows.